# New Atomic counter for each thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a thread hierarchy in my application. I'm trying to instantiate a new atomic counter common for each of the tree-thread. However each of the header is in his turn a new thread. Is their any way to do it ?
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do :

```
 @Assync
void start (){
atomic = new atomicInteger ();  //one new atomic counter for each upper thread

 sess.setMessageReceiverListener(new MessageReceiverListener() {atomic.increment});
 }
  
 
 
 void sendMess(List<Mess> l)
{
 for (Mess m: l)
{   execService.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
       ...
                }}


   }


   }
```

Comment: put the atomic counter instantiation outside of the start()?

Comment: In spring boot there is only one instance for each component , so I have  the same problem. the counter is common for all the upper threads . Is their a way to create independent ones for each of the upper threads ?

Comment: What about wrapping the AtomicInteger in a ThreadLocal?

Comment: I have just tries it. The problem with that approach is that NO thread get to access the atomic variable neither the upper thread nor the roots